# How to split Json response and get specific part using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am developing angular blockchain application using hyperledger composer tool.When i query the historian i got a response like in the below.

```
{

 transactionType:"org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant"

}
```

I display the transaction type using follwing code snippet.

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
    {{participant.transactionType}}
 </div>
```

The displayed part like this.

```
org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant
```

but I only want to display the 'AddParticipant' part in the response without 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.' part. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you just substring from the last index of `.` ? Like `t.substring(t.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)` where `t` is your string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that just do little string manipulation. Make use of JS .split() method which splits string by argument character/string.

`let arr = this.participant.transactionType.split(".");`

then `arr[arr.length-1]` is your required string part which you can bind to view. Like use below `{{txTyepe}}` in template binding

```
this.txType = arr[arr.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "substr" to pick a word from string but you need position of your word in your string first so :

```
const str = 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant'
let getPosition = str.indexOf('AddParticipant'); // get the position of AddParticipant
let getWord = str.substr(getPosition,13);
```

the length of AddParticipant is 13 
 also you can change the code above for better and cleaner and multi use code

```
const splitWord = (index)=>{
  const str = 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant'
  let strArray = str.split('.')
  let getPosition = str.indexOf('AddParticipant'); // get the position of AddParticipant
  let getWord = str.substr(getPosition,strArray[index].lenght); //you just need to change the number 

  return getWord;
}
console.log(splitWord(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the last "word" with regular expression :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  {{participant.transactionType.match(/\w+$/i)}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see your historian data it'll look something like this

```
'$namespace': 'org.hyperledger.composer.system',
'$type': 'HistorianRecord',
'$identifier': '6e43b959c39bdd0c15fe45587a8dc866f1fa854d9fea8498536e84b45e281b31',
'$validator': ResourceValidator { options: {} },
transactionId: '6e43b959c39bdd0c15fe45587a8dc866f1fa854d9fea8498536e84b45e281b31',
transactionType: 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.IssueIdentity',
transactionInvoked:
 Relationship {
   '$modelManager': [Object],
   '$classDeclaration': [Object],
   '$namespace': 'org.hyperledger.composer.system',
   '$type': 'IssueIdentity',
   '$identifier': '6e43b959c39bdd0c15fe45587a8dc866f1fa854d9fea8498536e84b45e281b31',
   '$class': 'Relationship' },
```

So, instead of taking **transactionType** you can use the **transactionInvoked** object. And then you can get whatever information you want from that object.
Finally your code should be like this

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
     {{participant.transactionInvoked.$type}}
 </div>
```

In my case it will give me transaction type as just 'IssueIdentity'.